# Trying to convert string to json in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am pretty sure that I am doing something very stupid..

I have a string:

```
s = '{"l":1,"oE":{"n":"name","rN":["1","2","3","3","5","6","7","8","9","10"],"dir":"out","ed":["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]}'
```

I did json.loads(s)

But I am getting an error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 328, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 72 (char 72)
```

Comment: the last element in rN is missing a quote, and oE doesn't have a closing bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a quotation mark in your code. Also a closing brace. Instead of:

```
s = '{"l":1,"oE":{"n":"name","rN":["1","2","3","3","5","6","7","8","9","10],"dir":"out","ed":["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]}'
```

use

```
s = '{"l":1,"oE":{"n":"name","rN":["1","2","3","3","5","6","7","8","9","10"],"dir":"out","ed":["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]}}'
```

You can figure this out from your stack trace:

```
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 72 (char 72)
```

If you look at the 72nd character in that line, you'll see that's where the error occurs.

Comment: You're also missing a closing brace (`}`) somewhere. I'm not sure exactly where you want it, but I stuck one in a place where it should work.

Comment: @user2052251 remmeber the } at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

`"10]` seems to be missing a `"`. Try `"10"]` instead.

Comment: You are missing a `}` somewhere, as @raser points out in a comment. It should go at the end of `"oE"` value, wherever that might be.